# How to fill and order an array from keyboard in Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, selection

Good morning everybody,
I'm trying to make a simple program to order some numbers (which they are in an array which is filled from the keyboard) in Java, with a maximum of 500 numbers. 
I don't remember how to set the cycle after the scanner.
Thanks

```
import java.util.*;
public static void main (String [] args) {
Scanner lettore = new Scanner (System.in);
int[] array = new int[500];

    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) 
        array[j]=input.nextInt() {
        boolean flag = false;
        for(int j = 0; j < array.length-1; j++) {


            //if j is higher than the next their values got exchanged              
            if(array[j]>array[j+1]) {
                int k = array[j];
                array[j] = array[j+1];
                array[j+1] = k;
                flag=true; //is true if the exchange has happened
            }


        }

        if(!flag) break; //if false in the last cycle you didn't have exchanges, so the program can end because the array has been ordered

    }
}
```

Comment: `array[j]=input.nextInt() {`???

Comment: What is the failure ? one thing I spotted is that you're trying to access `array[j+1]` and you're iterating till `array.length` which means you'll get an [`IndexOutOfBoundsException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html) and that you're using `j` before it was declared.

Comment: You need to provide a verifiable code sample.

Comment: Is using an array for sorting a requirement?

Comment: One stupid error was that i forgot to put the name of the class; and i don't reach to fill the array from the keyboard.